# I need to make a priority queue with strings that have add() and remove() functions with C++

Tags: c++, string, priority-queue

So I'm in this C++ class, and I don't seem to understand how to go about this problem.

Implement a priority queue for strings. A priority queue is similar to a regular queue except each item added to the queue also has an associated priority. For this problem, make the priority an integer where 0 is the highest priority and larger values are increasingly lower in priority.

The remove function should return and remove the item that has the highest priority, for example:

```
q.add("X",10);
q.add("Y",1);
q.add("Z",3);

cout << q.remove(); //returns Y
cout << q.remove(); //returns Z
cout << q.remove(); //returns X
```

.

Here is what I have so far.

http://pastebin.com/AgXL9dfq

Basically, I just need the add() and remove() functions, which I don't understand how to implement. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much STL can you use? For example, you could implement a priority queue with a `std::map` quite trivially.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're asking me, Dave. What do you mean by STL?

Comment: Google it. Rephrased: Can you use a [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: @Dave seeing as he's using `std::vector` in his code, i'm pretty sure he can use `std::map` as well.

Comment: I did google "C++ STL" and didn't find anything useful. As for std::map, I don't know. We haven't learned anything about it, afaik, but I don't see why not. He hasn't said we couldn't use anything.

Comment: @user2993567 Then use a [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), see how that goes over. Done. Also, I googled that same phrase and [the wiki page on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) seems plenty informative...

Comment: Well I don't understand how to use std::priority_queue. Think you could help me out a little further? If I wasn't having such a hard time with this problem I wouldn't have come to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's another solution using `std::map` and `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class priority_queue {
    std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> queue;
public:
    void add(int priority, std::string str) {
        if(!queue[priority].empty()) {
            queue[priority].push_back(str);
        } else {
            std::vector<std::string> vec;
            vec.push_back(str);
            queue[priority] = vec;
        }
    }
    std::string remove() {
        if(!queue.begin()->second.empty()) {
            std::string temp = queue.begin()->second[0];
            queue.begin()->second.erase(queue.begin()->second.begin());
            if(queue.begin()->second.empty())
                queue.erase(queue.begin());
            return temp;
        }
        std::cout << "ERROR: QUEUE EMPTY!" << std::endl;
        return "";
    }
};


int main() {
    priority_queue pq;

    pq.add(10, "hello");
    pq.add(10, "world");
    pq.add(11, "how");
    pq.add(12, "are");
    pq.add(13, "you?");

    std::cout << pq.remove() << std::endl;
    std::cout << pq.remove() << std::endl;
    std::cout << pq.remove() << std::endl;
    std::cout << pq.remove() << std::endl;
    std::cout << pq.remove() << std::endl;
}
```

it generates the following output:

```
hello
world
how
are
you?
```

it works by using a map which has a key value of `int` denoting priority, and a `std::vector<std::string>` as it's value, i.e. a collection of values with the same priority.

`add()` method checks if there's already a value present in the map with the given priority - if it does, it simply pushes the string value on to the back of the vector, if it does not, it creates a new vector, pushes back the value, and assigns it to `map[priority]`.

`remove()` method checks if the queue is empty, and if not, it returns the appropriate value by taking it from the front of the value container vector; if the "popped" string happens to be the last on in the vector, it means there are no longer values tied to it's priority, and the entire entry is deleted from the map, so as not to cause further problems.

Comment: http://puu.sh/5imch.png - Get this error when I try to compile this. Any idea why?

Comment: if you have c++11 support, the try compiling like this `g++ -o q.out q.cpp -std=c++11`. if not, the change this statement `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> queue;` to this `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string> > queue;`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jfBC5DnG - This is ultimately what I used. Thank you all for all your help!

Comment: @user2993567 no problem, just make sure to test the code thoroughly and take the time to actually understand what's going on. also, seeing as you didn't know about `std::map`, make sure to read up on it to see what it is and how it works!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the heap data structure. A heap is a binary tree for which the following conditions hold:

- Every node has a parent, a left and a right child (they could probably be `NULL`)
- Every node has a key and a priority
- If `p` is parent of `u`, then `p.priority` < `u.priority`

Knowing all these, you can implement the operations `insert(key, priority)` and `remove()` efficiently. More specifically, each one of the mentioned operations has a complexity of `O(log N)`, where N is the size of the priority queue. More about the heap data structure can be found at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure). Below I post some code I wrote (I haven't tested it a lot, but i think it works).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define MAXN 100005
#define L(n) (2*n)
#define R(n) (2*n+1)
#define P(n) (int)(n/2)

struct Node {
  int p;
  string s;
  void swap(Node &other) {
    Node tmp = (Node){p, s};
    p = other.p, s = other.s;
    other.p = tmp.p, other.s = tmp.s;
  }
};

template<typename Key, typename Priority>
struct PriorityQueue {
private:
  vector<pair<Key, Priority> > pq;
  int size;

  void bubble_up(int u) {
    while(P(u)) {
      if(pq[P(u)].second > pq[u].second) {
        swap(pq[u], pq[P(u)]);
        u = P(u);
      } else break;
    }
  }

  void bubble_down(int u) {
    while(L(u) <= size) {
      int pp = min(pq[u].second, pq[L(u)].second);
      if(R(u) <= size) pp = min(pp, pq[R(u)].second);
      if(pp == pq[u].second) break;
      else if(pp == pq[L(u)].second) {
        swap(pq[u], pq[L(u)]);
        u = L(u);
      } else {
        swap(pq[u], pq[R(u)]);
        u = R(u);
      }
    }
  }

public:
  PriorityQueue() : pq(1), size(0) {}

  void add(Key key, Priority priority) {
    pq.push_back(make_pair(key, priority));
    bubble_up(++size);
  }

  Key remove() {
    Key ret = pq[1].first;
    swap(pq[1], pq[size--]);
    pq.pop_back();
    bubble_down(1);
    return ret;
  }
};

int main() {
  PriorityQueue<string, int> Q;

  Q.add("X", 10);
  Q.add("Y", 1);
  Q.add("Z", 3);
  Q.add("K", 7);

  cout << Q.remove() << endl;
  cout << Q.remove() << endl;
  cout << Q.remove() << endl;
  cout << Q.remove() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I put the functions `add()` and `remove()` into a structure called `PriorityQueue`. I also extended the structure to accept other types of keys and priorities. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Edit: Wait, this is still technically wrong. The question asks for the main method to have q.add and q.remove. Thanks regardless, this will help a ton.

Comment: After playing with this a bit I came up with the following: http://pastebin.com/83ph7gAW - But the last one in the que isn't shown. It prints the first two, but just a blank line for the last. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2993567 I edited and extended the code, I hope it helps :)